# Linking models in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model to create an article, and I want to save the id of the user that created that article also. I am doing this, but I have an error. I really appreciate any help!

```
let articleSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
    markdown: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
```

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'USER_ROLE',
        enum: validRoles
    }
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {message: '{PATH} must be unique'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And in the post method of the article I have this:
How can I access the user??

```
const article = new Article({
        title: body.title,
        description: body.description,
        markdown: body.markdown,
        user: req.user._id
    });
```

Comment: Plz mention what error u are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a problem in your article schema. Try to change

```
user: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
```

to

```
user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
```

Then, to display the author information try this in your routes file:

```
app.get('your-get-article-route', async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const articles = await Article.find().populate('user');
    // other pieces of code if needed
    res.status(200).json({ articles });
    } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'an error occured!'});
)
```

If you're not familiar with async/await, you can do it with promises:

```
app.get('your-get-article-route', (req, res) => {
    const articles = Article.find().populate('user').then((articles) => {
       // other pieces of code if needed
       res.status(200).json({ articles });
    }).catch((error) => {
       res.status(400).json({message: 'an error occured'}
     );
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made those changes, but I get an error saying that _id is undefined. I think I have a problem with the authentication. Thanks again!